# Find neighbouring prime numbers using BASH

Tags: bash, validation, primes

I had a pretty hard homework (hard for beginners like me).
We had to find given number's nearest neighbouring primes.
User input must be a two-digit number and can be prime. The results must be printed on screen, seperated by whitespaces.
For input validaton:

```
while read -p "Give me a two-digit numer: " n && [[ -z $n ]] || [[ ! $n =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [ $n -lt 10 ] || [ $n -gt 99 ]
do
    echo -e "\e[31mLet's try that again ...\e[0m"
done
```

I was thinking about using an already initialized array, containing the prime numbers from 7 to 101 and somehow compare it with the user input.

```
# Initialize an array with possible prime numbers
primes=(7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101)

# Create an inverted version of 'primes' array ... because of reasons ...
for (( i="${#primes[@]}-1" ; i>=0 ; i-- ));
do
    rprimes+="${primes[i]} "
done
```

Who else likes 'for' loops?

```
# To find the next prime number
i=0
for i in ${primes[@]}
do
    if [ $i -gt $n ]
    then
        gtn=$i
    break
    fi
done

# To find the previous prime number in the inverted 'rprimes' array
for i in ${rprimes[@]}
do
    if [ $i -lt $n ]
    then
        ltn=$i
    break
    fi
done

# Results:
echo "$ltn $n $gtn"
```

The script works, but I would really like to know, if there is a way to find the 'previous' value without the need to create an inverted array.

Sorry for mah english!

## Solution/Edit:

```
for (( i=0; for (( i=0; i<=${#primes[@]}; i++ ));
do
    if [ ${primes[i]} -lt $n ] && [ ${primes[i+1]} -ge $n ]
    then
        ltn=${primes[i]}
    break
    fi
done
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802654/find-neighbouring-prime-numbers-using-bash#comment55372977_33803115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already understand `for` loops clearly, since you use one to create the reversed array rprimes. Just run a forward `for` on the primes array. Isn't the condition for `ltn=${primes[i]}` just

```
[ ${primes[i]} -lt $n ] && [ ${primes[i+1]} -ge $n ]
```

?

And the condition for `gtn=${primes[i+1]}` likewise

```
[ ${primes[i]} -le $n ] && [ ${primes[i+1]} -gt $n ]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just find the index of the prime you're interested in, it's then easy to look around just by ±1:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#primes[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    if (( n <= primes[i] )) ; then
        p=$(( n == primes[i] ))
        echo ${primes[i-1]} $n ${primes[i+p]}
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this one out as well!